How can I link two plates in such a way that one is able to freely move in 2D planar directions relative to another?
I'm designing a mapping robot that basically bumps into wall and records the position in its log. As safety mechanism I want to install kill switches in min 3 directions around the roughly circular periphery of the bot. In case the bot hits the wall too hard the nearest switches from the hitting direction will activate and stop the bot. I believe a better way to achieve this result is installing a circular ring around the bot's chassis that is in constant contact with all switches in equilibrium position. If the bump event happens, the ring will be pressed in that direction activating the switches nearby. My question is how do I link such a ring to the chassis so that it is  fixed but able to freely move in XY plane relative to bot's body?

A string under tension held around the periphery, that as soon as it touches it looses tension allowing 1 single switch to kill all the motors.
